# Solace bridge Inbound subscription not working

Tags: solace, solace-mq

I'm running two software broker, A and B, in docker, and tried to setup bidirectional bridge between them.

The first (subscribing B topics from A) seems to work as expected, but subscribing A's topics from B, the bridge status is always down.

These are the stats on broker B's manager, the remote address is using a different port (it was set to 10.5.0.5:55555) --->

| Remote Message VPN | default |
| --- | --- |
| Remote PubSub+ Name | v:834452a21b4e |
| Remote Address | 10.5.0.5:37296 |
| Local Interface | intf0:1 |
| Establisher | Local |
| Inbound State | Ready-InSync |

I've been banging head against wall to get this up. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:
I was using ansible solace to configure the brokers. The issue is gone if I add the bridge, remote vpn and subscriptions before users and ACL.